# Find not working as expected in Solaris 10

Tags: find, solaris, solaris-10

```
find / ! -path "/home" -name "*thing*"
```

Gives:

```
find: bad option -path
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
```

It seems like some options in find in Solaris 10 don't behave like they do on Linux. For example, to negate something, I need to do "!" instead of "-not". Essentially my problem is I'm trying to find something but exclude a directory because of how long it would take to traverse it. However, I can't do this if I can't specify a path to exclude.

It's strange how -name works but -path doesn't. I'm quite happy to use an alternative to find if it gets the job done ofc.

Comment: Not useful, doesn't show anything about selecting/excluding specific directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `man` fails you ask Google.....

"solaris find exclude path" yields

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23077/how-to-exclude-a-list-of-full-directory-paths-in-find-command-on-solaris

Comment: That is where your question belongs BTW. StackOverflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know there was a Unix SE site.